# UISearchDisplayDelegate Deprecation Work-Around

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I noticed that basically everything in [UISearchDisplayDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/index.html) is deprecated. Being as how it was the only way I was taught to implement a Search Bar and Search Display Controller, what would be a good work-around?

Sample code being:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) { // 'searchDisplayContoller' is now deprecated
        return [searchList count];
    } else {
        return [initialList count];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UISearchController` should be replacing it...

Class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html

Apple's notes about replacement, scroll to UIKit Framework section:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html

Comment: Thanks! Went digging around to see if there were any samples and found this if anybody was interested: [link](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController)

Comment: @collinhaines did you figure out what's the replacement for `self.searchDisplayController`? `self.searchController` says "has no member searchController"